# How to reference the current spreadsheet in a named range in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets

Whithin the same document (workbook), whenever I create named ranges, I have something like `Sheet1!A1` but it is always refering to `Sheet1`. Is there any way in which I could refer to the **current** spreadsheet instead?

Something like `this!A1` which will turn into `Sheet1!A1` if I'm currently in `Sheet1` or `Sheet200!A1` if I'm in `Sheet200`.

The purpuse is to reuse the same formulas (with already have the named intervals) in all the spreadsheets of the workbook. I found it rather stupid this global and fixed reference. This way I always have to recreate my formulas for each spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A named range refers to a specific range of cells on a specific sheet - I don't see that changing anytime soon.

But here is a custom function you can put into your spreadsheet's script that will "localize" ranges for you. This code is also available for download [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/4661225).

```
/*
 * Return a string with the A1 notation for the given range, with
 * the sheet reference removed. To use in spreadsheet functions,
 * enclose with INDIRECT().
 *
 * Example: 
 *   =index(INDIRECT(localizeNamedRange(NamedRange1)),12,4)
 *
 * @param {string} rangeName  The name of an existing range in the
 *                        active spreadsheet. It does not matter which
 *                        sheet the range was defined for.
 *
 * @return {string}       The cell range from the provided rangeName,
 *                        in A1 notation.
 */
function localizeNamedRange( rangeName ) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get range by name
  var origRange = sheet.getRangeByName(rangeName);

  // Get notation for the range, without sheet reference.
  var notation = "";
  if (origRange !== null) {
    notation = origRange.getA1Notation();
  }

  // Return range in A1 notation
  debugger;   // pause to examine if running in debugger
  return ( notation );
}
```

Here's an example. NamedRange1 has been defined as "Sheet1!A10:A22". If we put `=localizeNamedRange(NamedRange1)` in a cell, it will return `A10:A22`, without the reference to `Sheet1`. That's a string, so if we want to use it in a formula that expects a range, we need to convert it - and do that, we use the built-in function `INDIRECT()`.

On Sheet1 we have a formula in cell A3 that calculates the average value of NamedRange1. Here's how to define that formula to make it localize-able:

```
(A3) =AVERAGE(INDIRECT(localizeNamedRange(NamedRange1));
```

If you now copy Sheet1 into a new Sheet2, you'll find that the formula still works, and that it performs its calculations on the data on Sheet2, even though the Named Range refers to Sheet1.